# Add Lightbox To WordPress Native Gallery

Tags: filters, jquery, hooks, gallery

Is there a way to check if a gallery is linked to an attachment page or to an image file via jQuery or WP filter?

I'm trying to add a lightbox to gallery image that is linked to image file. But I can't do it since there's no way to tell the difference between image linked to attachment page or image file in the html codes generated by WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a difference in the HTML output for images inserted alone or via `[gallery]`.

A direct image link will output an `<a href="">` to an actual image mime type, like:
 `<a href="some-image.jpg">`

An attachment `<a href="">` outputs an attachment URI like:
`<a href="some-link?attachment_id=126"` or `../attachment/2013/`

As for a filter I don't think there is a way unless you parse `the_content` for the above matches.